# How to know if openId connect provider support single page applications like angular App

Tags: single-page-application, openid

I have a task to give my team leader feedback if our client openId connect service support SPA or not.
so i want to know if any criteria exist on openID Auth provider to support single page applications.

Answer (score 1):

All OpenID Connect providers do support SPA applications. If it is a SPA, mobile application or a backend client does not matter.

However you need to be aware of the security implications, a good stating point is this video [alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck)
and this best practice document  [OAuth 2.0 for Browser-Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps)

Answer (score 0):

As Tore mentioned, all OIDC Providers support SPAs, as it doesn't really matter where the client resides. SPAs, though introduce some security risks around handling tokens in the browser. You may want to have a look at implementing an SPA with a lightweight Backend-for-Frontend component, which will allow your SPA to rely on session cookies, not tokens. This will even further decouple the SPA from the Authorization Server.

You can have a look at a demo of such a setup that we created at Curity: https://curity.io/resources/learn/back-end-for-front-end/